# Value clear after focusout of the textbox with datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd/M/yy", 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true,  
        yearRange: '1960:1994', 
        defaultDate: '01/Jun/94' 
    });
});

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateOfBirth" class="textbox_shorts datepicker1" autocomplete="off" ></asp:TextBox>
```

The above mentioned is my code.

The date can be shown in the textbox when I choose the date on datepicker, however, after focusout of the text box the value will be disappeared. How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work for you

```
$('.datepicker1').focusout(function(){ $(this).text('')})
```